# I would like to update my script form google sheets to get range of active row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning everyone :),

I'm struggling withe a problem for some time and I was wondering that anyone can help me here.

I wrote some script that is copying and pasting rows from one sheet to another when Q column checkbox is TRUE. Please see code below :

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  if(ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 16 && ss.getActiveCell().getRow() > 1 && ss.getActiveCell().isChecked()) {

  var source = ss.getRange("TRACKER!B2:N2");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,2);
  source.copyTo(destRange,{contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();

  }
}
```

My QQ is how to change last script input :

`source.clear();`

That instead of clearing it just delete whole row, and also how to change

`var source = ss.getRange("TRACKER!B2:N2");`

That B2:N2 will be change into B?:N? where "?" depending which row in column Q was selected.

Thank You in advance

Have a good day

Mariusz

Answer (score 2):

When the `onEdit()` trigger [fires](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events),

> Apps Script passes the function an event object as an argument,
>   typically called `e`. The event object contains information about the
>   context that caused the trigger to fire.

So you could change your script to:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); // Assumes the active sheet is called 'TRACKER'

  var activeCell = e.source.getActiveCell();

  if ( activeCell.getColumn() == 17 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && activeCell.isChecked() ) {

    var source = activeSheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), 2, 1, 13); // Columns B through N

    var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ARCHIVE");

    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2);

    source.copyTo(destRange,{contentsOnly: true});

    source.clearContent(); // To clear just the contents and not delete the row

  }
}
```

Column Q = column 17.

This script assumes that the active sheet with the checkboxes is called 'TRACKER'

[Ref docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) for `onEdit()`

[Ref docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) for getting cells, ranges in spreadsheets and copying and clearing them.

Comment: e.source.getActiveSheet(); -TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined / when var "source" is defined below e.source.getActiveSheet() it won't work like intended

Comment: It might be saying that because you are manually trying to trigger the function - in which case there is no `e` to process. The script you wrote will work when manually triggered as it has no input parameter. But `onEdit(e)` will work _only_ when you edit the Spreadsheet,

Comment: Great, thank you for this explanation, your hints are very helpful, just got one last qq. If I will make some changes like conditional formatting in the triggered cell is it possible that script will stop working ? because right now it stop and I'm just not able to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: It should not. `onEdit()` is triggered only when "when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet." [See docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite)

Answer (score 0):

Hello ADW and thank you for quick reply,

I have update the code like this :

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  if(ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 16 && ss.getActiveCell().getRow() > 1 && ss.getActiveCell().isChecked()) {   
    var source = ss.getRange("TRACKER!B" + ss.getActiveCell().getRow()+ ":N"+ss.getActiveCell().getRow());
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE");
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,2);
    source.copyTo(destRange,{contentsOnly: true});
    ss.deleteRow(ss.getActiveCell().getRow());    
  }
}
```

and it seems to work fine now but nevertheless once again thank you for the code it surly help me to solve this query.

Comment: also getClolumn() == 16 I have just update as the las colum so insted of this I wrote getLastColumn